# Read the value of a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, windowlistener, changelistener

How to read the value of a JSlider?

I am using sliders in my program, something I have not used before but I am struggling to display the changes made to it!

The problem is, the `JLabel` displays the value of the slider when you open the program (50) but when you change the value the label does not.

Here is the code:

Setting up the slider (in setUpMenuItems class):

```
sensitivitySlider2 = new JSlider();//direction , min , max , current
sensitivitySlider2.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,10));
sensitivitySlider2.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
sensitivitySlider2.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
sensitivitySlider2.setPaintLabels(true);
sensitivitySlider2.setPaintTicks(true);
sensitivitySlider2.setPaintTrack(true);
sensitivitySlider2.setAutoscrolls(true);
sensitivitySlider2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

sensitivitySlider2.setBounds (15,200,250,100);

propertiesPanel.add(sensitivitySlider2);
```

establishing the listener:

```
private void registerComponentsForEvents()
  {
    // Register all the JButton objects for action events

    miniButton.addActionListener (this);
    applyButton.addActionListener (this);
    exitButton.addActionListener (this);
    sensitivitySlider2.addChangeListener(this);


  }
```

Window listener and declaring methods to make concrete:

```
void addWindowListener(Window w) {
      w.addWindowListener(this);
    }

//React to window events.


    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }

    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
    }
```

ChangeEvent:

```
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
          JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
          if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
              int sleepSense = (int)source.getValue();


    }
}
```

and then this line to set a JLabel as the value:

```
sleepSense2 = String.valueOf(sleepSense);
```

Comment: *"Here is the code:"*  What on Earth does a `WindowListener` have to do with this?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I took it from a tutorial of setting up a Jslider, I am clutching at straws with my slim knowledge

Comment: Make your knowledge fatter by reading the link.  ..and `JSlider` has two upper case letters.  If you cannot spell it, copy/paste.

Comment: Are you able to run the examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html#eg)?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic, but, i will share my thoughts on it.

I believe you do not need to have the following code written like this just to get the value. (Using if statement)

```
if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
          int sleepSense = (int)source.getValue();
```

you can just be well of with the following

```
JSlider mySlider= new JSlider();
mySlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
          public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
              int sleepSense = mySlider.getValue();
    }
```

then you can use the value "sleepSense" anywhere in your program.